# Different price on product page and cart page

Tags: magento-1.8, cart

For some reason I'm getting a different price prior to adding a product to the cart.
For example at product and category page the prics is $44.97 however at cart page it's beeing displayed as 45.00 (note two decimals here as well)

I want the price at cart to be $44.97 and not $45.00.

Comment: There might be some tax calculations in between that transition.

Comment: Checked the tax settings and no taxes are added according to admin. So must be something else.